# How much "single paged" a complex application can be?

Tags: javascript, dom, architecture, browser, single-page-application

I'm working on a quite a large application with several sub modules. Each of the sub module can be of complex functionality with many panels and UI components. I had done smaller scale projects before as a single page application, but this time worried on the fact that my DOM will not be refreshed for a long time if user keeps on working across many modules.

When I analyze how Facebook operates, I see it works as a single page app most of the time. But time to time it refreshes the whole DOM with an action of the user (apparently it is random OR based on user activity count).

Is their any pattern or best practice on how one might create such large applications as single page, without compromising DOM performance?

(I'm NOT looking for coding techniques to keep the memory foot print low.. but for a design approach for the total application)

Comment: Finally I wrote a blog post about it: http://blog.hasith.net/2012/11/how-much-multi-page-single-page.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no shame in refreshing the page. An application doesn't **have** to be strictly single-paged.

If you have controls on your page, their actions should remain contained within that page. But if the user goes on an entirely different part of the application, there's no reason why he shouldn't be able to simply navigate to that specific page.

Comment: @Hasith: Also, consider having a look at the MVC pattern. Which abstracts the logic from "pages" and moves them into "controllers" and "models".

Comment: Sure I do use MVVM on this project. Infact I'm the author of BoilerplateJS (http://boilerplatejs.org) and had used it for several projects successfully so far.. The new project I'm up with bit too complex with a lot of functionalities.. so now thinking of combining single page with multipage approach...

Answer (score 1):

Destroying DOM nodes, or setting `innerHTML = ''` for the panel, that has to be changed, just before the change occurs should be fine. I suppose the UI elements have a `destroy` or similar functionality.

Also consider unsetting all javascript variables involved in the functionality of the panel, that should be cleared.

Comment: As far as I know removing elements from DOM really doesn't mean you are taking them away from memory.. still they remain in the memory. I'm somewhat knowledgeable of memory handling techniques.. but with this question, I look for a more of a design approach... for example combining single page and multipage behavior is something I'm considering about.

Comment: I don't think you need to ponder about that until you actually have a memory leak

Comment: @Bergi: The question owner doesn't mention leaks, I think he/she is rather concerned about the amount of memory used.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to have an **Application core** that controls the life cycle of your modules. And each of your module will then have well defined interface like launch(), destroy() etc or whatever makes sense. So when the destroy() function is called it will empty the html as well Javascript object's that stores app data. Nicholas Zakas has excellent presentation on a large scale Javascript application. Hope it helps.

[Scalable Javascript application architecture by Nicholas Zakas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw)

Comment: thanks.. but I already use all these modularization techniques with http://boilerplatejs.org

Comment: Thanks. I am new to javascript and boilerplate.js sure looks very structured and promising.